# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 10208: invalid start byte

Tags: web-crawler, urllib

import urllib.request

response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
print(response.read().decode('utf-8'))

maybe for google, I may not use utf-8, however, how can I get the script from its website?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/pythoncode/wikiSpider/venv/project10.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 10247: invalid start byte

Comment: Was the site returned as UTF-8 encoded (correctly)? What happens when saving the file and attempting to open it in an editor (that provides a clear indicator of an invalid byte)?